# How to use selenium.waitforvalue command without javascript?

Tags: javascript, automation, rpa, g1ant

I haven't work on javascript but I do want to use waitforvalue command in chrome as I have done in internet explorer.

```
ie.waitforvalue script document.getElementsByClassName("footer").length expectedvalue 1
```

Is there any other format in which I can use selenium.waitforvalue command without using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no possibility in G1ANT to use the `selenium.waitforvalue` or `ie.waitforvalue` commands without also using javascript.

By the way your code can be improved. I guess that you want to just wait for the `footer` class elements to be loaded and not specifically check if the elements number is 1.

This is how you can check if any elements of the `footer` class are loaded:

```
selenium.waitforvalue script ‴return !!document.getElementsByClassName("footer").length > 0‴ expectedvalue true
```

or if you're using the `ie.waitforvalue` command:

```
ie.waitforvalue script ‴!!document.getElementsByClassName("footer").length > 0‴ expectedvalue true
```